# Run next js minified build (.NEXT) version

Tags: next.js13, production

Step 1 : we created next.js project with below command

```
    npx create-next-app@latest test-app
```

step 2 : This is the following code for package.json
{
"name": "test-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"export": "next export",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.18.2",
"next": "13.5.5",
"next-images": "^1.8.5",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^8",
"eslint-config-next": "13.5.5"
}
}

step 3 : in order run build we are using,
npm start

but we are not able to run test demo.